# need AS3 movieclip parent child related functions

Tags: actionscript-3, parent

hi i've taken on a new coding technique and its leaving me a little stranded, alot of concepts ive previously applied now take new syntax and sometimes create unforseen problems.

OK, so i make multiplayer flash games. In order to cut down on clutter i no longer use multiple class.as files, instead, i have my stage, and one library object called triggers, which i place just out of sight in the upper left of the stage. i then make a class.as file for this one movieclip object, and from there i instantiate everything else in my program - so far a login splash-screen movieclip, a game-window movieclip, a lobby movieclip, and finally the game-instance movieclip. these come in and out of .visible appropriately, and when not in use they are stored at off screen x and y values, they progress sequentially based on userinput. additionally i have public arrays which store importantMessages[], myplayerarray[], myArrowsarray[], myenemyarray[]

now my biggest issue at the moment is i'll recieve in from the server the variables i need to build a new arrow and monster unit -- so ill do like movieclip orc, with orc.speed, orc.xstartlocation orc.hp and so on, and ill have a similar arrow movieclip with arrow.speed, arrow.gravity, and so on. both of these movieclips, with added properties, are then pushed onto the appropriate public arrays, and *not* added to the stage, but instead, are added to the stage.add(gamewindow:Movieclip) (the reasoning behind this is so that later if i want to move everything on the stage at once, they are already oriented on a single cohesive movieclip, then i can just move this movieclip)

ok now onto the problem stuff, when i have two gamewindow.movieclips collide, like an arrow versus an orc (lets say arrow13 hittest orc42 == true) i remove the arrow movieclip object from the gamewindow:movieclip and splice it from its myarrowarray, however, even though the graphic dissapears, it continues to move its current trajectory and hit everything else on its way. I believe the reasoning behind this is because during the creation of the movieclip with its variables, i include an eventlistener on enterframe, i think its removing the clip but not the event listener (see very bottom for instantiated arrow Movieclip class)

so this brings me to my concise question:
QUESTION ONE:
is it possible to not only gamewindow.removeChild(arrow13) but also gamewindow.removeChild(arrow13[and all variables and eventlisteners at once])

QUESTIONTWO:
my second question is a bit easier: since switching to movieclip() instead of object() ive been using brute force, what would be a 1 line piece of code to do all of the following:

var newarrow:MovieClip = new playerarrow();

newarrow.theowner = username

newarrow.thespeed = speed

newarrow.thegravity = gravity

newarrow.thepower = power

newarrow.arrownumber = arrowid

and my third question goes back to my splashscreen movieclips idea, im having trouble playing around with thier z-values

basically when i call the importantmessage() its creates a new movieclip in the lower left, which alpha fades to 0 and it removes itself, however i have a problem where my new movieclip windows will overwrite these messages since they were added a split second after, the example in my program is i will have 2 messages spit out stage.add "attempting to connect to server" "connected" then the next major function is invoked and it instantiates the loginsplash:movieclip = new loginwindow -- i've tried taking this new stage.addchild(loginsplash) and do setChildIndex(loginsplash, 0) as well as -1 and 1. both 1's are out of bounds and 0 produces : The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
QUESTION THREE: 
so if i have gamemsg z = 0 gamemsg2 z = 1 and loginsplash z = (0?), how can i get the game messages to always lay on top ( i think its more of a referenceing problem then anything else

========================================

connection.addMessageHandler("newarrow",

function(m:Message, username, speed, gravity, power, arrowid)

```
    {
        var newarrow:MovieClip = new playerarrow();
        newarrow.theowner = username
        newarrow.thespeed = speed
        newarrow.thegravity = gravity
        newarrow.thepower = power
        newarrow.arrownumber = arrowid

        for each(var p in myplayerarray)
            if (p.mpname == username){
                newarrow.x = p.theanimation.x + 100
                newarrow.y = p.theanimation.y + 100
            }
        myarrowarray.push(newarrow)
        gw.addChild(newarrow)
        newarrow.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, arrowenterframe)

        function arrowenterframe(e:Event){
            newarrow.thegravity = 0    //+=.6
            speed = 5
            newarrow.x = newarrow.x+speed
            newarrow.y = newarrow.y + newarrow.thegravity

            //ROTATE FUNCTION
            newarrow.rotation = Math.atan(newarrow.thegravity / speed ) /(Math.PI/180)
            if (speed < 0) {newarrow.rotation +=180}

            for each(var d in myenemyarray){
                if (newarrow.hitTestObject(d.orcicon)){
                    connection.send("arrowhitmonster", newarrow.arrownumber, d.monsternumber) 
                    trace("hitting monster")
                }
            }

            if(newarrow.hitTestObject(gw.theground)){


               }

        }
    })
```

Comment: Q1: not possible. But you can add a listener with parameter `useWeakReference` set to true, this way if you finally invalidate all links to that object, its listeners will also get detached. Q2: why do you strive for one-liners? This code is good as is, assigning necessary properties. Q3: perhaps you should switch your message display approach to one instance of a MC at a time, changing its text and hiding it once login prompt appears? About your z-index issue, `mc.parent.setChildIndex(mc,mc.parent.numChildren-1)` will get your `mc` to the topmost position possible by your display hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

**Q1** ... is possible, but not with a single command. I would recommend you use the [casalib](http://casalib.org/) (which I tend to recommend often) If you use CasaMovieClip instead of MovieClip, it extends it by adding some additional functions that deal with these issues like `removeEventListeners()` and `removeAllChildrenAndDestroy()`(which removes listeners). With the event listeners, just be aware that it destroys only events that this object is listening to, and not the listeners that other objects have to this mc. Instead of trying to convert assets to use CasaMovieClip, you could also just look at the code and implement it over top of your classes/MCs

Another alternative to dealing with event listeners is to switch to using [signals](https://github.com/robertpenner/as3-signals) by Robert Penner. It's a much more elegant way of working with event notifications, and by the sounds of your setup (relying on few classes with big reach), it might work better when all communication between objects is happening through a single channel rather than being handled by every object individually.

**Q2** - you could create a factory function.

```
public function createMC($mc:MovieClip,$owner:String,$speed:int,...etc):MovieClip{
  $mc.theowner = $owner;
  // etc.
  return $mc;
}
```

or

```
public function createMC($mc:MovieClip,$properties:Object):MovieClip{
  $mc.theowner = $owner;
  for (var $property:String in $properties)
    if ($mc.hasOwnProperty($property))
      $mc[$property] = $properties[$property];
  return $mc;
}
```

where you call the function like this `var newarrow:MovieClip = createMC(new playerarrow(), { theowner:username});`

but I'm not sure why you would want to really

**Q3** - the way I deal with these is set up movie clip holders. The critical messages will always be on top, the game menu bellow, the game background always on bottom. In the main view I would have a gameholder MC and above the menu and above that the criticalMessage holder, any objects that are added and removed are only within the appropriate holder.